# How do you test the accelerometer of samsung sdk in VS2008 C#

Tags: c#, accelerometer, windows-mobile-6

are there example codings i could look into?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to look at the official docs @ http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.list.do?platformId=2.